# LCDS RemoteObject vs BlazeDS RemoteObject

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds, lcds

I'm beginner in Flex so please bear with me. I'm working on an application where I have to change a Flex application using LCDS into a BlazeDS one. The current LCDS based application is using only RPC functionality which is present in BlazeDS as well.

I read over the internet that both LCDS and BlazeDS are being developed by Adobe now. I downloaded the BlazeDS turnkey (demo application) and found that even the libraries under the "lib" folder are the same as that of my current LCDS based application.

Furthermore, APMO the way configurations are done in remoting-confix.xml & service-config.xml are also same.

**My question is:**

1. If everything seems same in LCDS RPC and BlazeDS RPC then where is the difference or am I missing something crucial here?
2. Also if both LCDS and BlazeDS are developed by Adobe and the libraries are same, then is there any real need to change the application from LCDS to BlazeDS. I know LCDS is paid and BlazeDS is free, but I don't understand where will I make changes in the application to make it BlazeDS if the libraries are same in both cases?
3. Finally, is there any difference how we create & call RemoteObject in LCDS and in BlazeDS?

Kindly reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LCDS has more features that are not present in blazeds and is designed to be more scalable. if you are not using any specific feature to LCDS then its painless to move to blazeds. for most apps (non enterprisey apps), blazeds will do just fine. remoteobject calls are the same.
there is also graniteds as another option.